# moment date format giving wrong result

Tags: angular, momentjs

Angular code:

```
console.log(
  moment('2013-07-29T00:00:00+00:00').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
);
```

is giving result: 2013-07-28 instead of 2013-07-29.

Can you please let me know what is wrong with it?

Comment: Time zones, perhaps?

Comment: Basically moment convert the time you provide into the timezone of your system (if you pass the offset in time)...Thats why when you pass the time 2013-07-29T00:00:00+00:00 with offset 0 (time of london) its converts the time to your system time and thats why when its 2013-07-29 in london you got 2013-07-28 in your timezone

Comment: Thanks Ankit and jonrsharpe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the moment object first and then use format.

Try this:

```js
var res = moment("2013-07-29T00:00:00+00:00", "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm").format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm");
console.log(res);
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```